# Selenium multiple errors: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#name"}

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, testing, junit

I am trying to test my website using Selenium and am often experiencing an network error, but when I  sync my time it allows me to connect as usual. Then when I can actually run the test I get the following error:

```
AssertEquals failed expected: 'Register' actually 'localhost'.
```

Because of this I changed the expected to 'localhost' temporarily and now I am getting this error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#name"}
```

Despite the fact that my html:

```
<div class="col-8">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name" pattern="^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$" title="Please enter letters only and 2 names, with a space separating them." class="form-control" required minlength="2" maxlength="20" placeholder="Name"/>
</div>
```

Clearly includes the 'id="name"' attribute. I am worried that these 2 issues are connected and that possibly the correct page is not being shown but I don't know how to fix it, thanks for any help.

Full Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
public class SeleniumTests {

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateAnAccount() throws Exception {

        if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedrivermac");
        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        }

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        webDriver.get("http://localhost:8080/register");

        assertEquals("Register", this.webDriver.getTitle());

        //Create a new account and create a new project and contribute to own project.

        WebElement name = webDriver.findElement(By.id("name")); // the name field.
        name.sendKeys("Tim Stephen"); //enter a name
        WebElement email = webDriver.findElement(By.id("email")); // the username field.
        email.sendKeys("timstephen@outlook.com"); //enter a username
        WebElement password = webDriver.findElement(By.id("password")); // the password field.
        password.sendKeys("ExamplePassword72-"); //enter a password
        WebElement confirmPassword = webDriver.findElement(By.id("confirmPassword")); // the confirm password field.
        confirmPassword.sendKeys("ExamplePassword72-"); //enter a password

        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // waits 2 seconds before pressing submit button.
        webDriver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

        //section for filling in user information.
        assertEquals("Landing", this.webDriver.getTitle());
}
}
```

[image: The chrome webpage is refusing to connect.]

Comment: Is the element with `id = name` unique ? is it in Selenium view port ? Did you check for iframe  ? also put some sleep and then check

Comment: @cruisepandey The id is unique for that element on that html file, but it is not the only element with id name across all of the html templates, does that matter? I tried changing to a unique id but now I get expected: <Register> but was: <>                                                                                            I am unsure how to check for iframe or what you mean by selenium view port. It is in IDEA I am just executing the class containing the selenium tests.

Comment: @cruisepandey I have added an image above showing what I see in chrome.

Comment: the image that you've shared, does not show the actual title.

Comment: @cruisepandey Its localhost

Comment: this will fail in that case `assertEquals("Register", this.webDriver.getTitle());` cause  `this.webDriver.getTitle()` would return localhost, and you are comparing that with `Register`